# kmem_cache_* creates contiguous memory?

Tags: caching, memory-management, linux-kernel

Am I right assuming that a memory slab created and allocated with `kmem_cache_create` and `kmem_cache_alloc` is contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A kmem_cache consists of 1 or more slabs.
- A slab consists of 1 or more contiguous pages.

So when you call `kmem_cache_alloc`, it returns you a piece of memory in a slab which consists of 1 or more contiguous pages.

But if you call `kmem_cache_alloc` twice, the 2 pieces of memory you get may not contiguous.

And `kmem_cache_create` only creates and initializes the data structure for a kmem_cache and do not allocate the memories.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, kmalloc() and kmem_cache_*() APIs are returning contiguous memory - which is handled by slab allocator....

vmalloc() can be used to ask big chunk of memory and it will return "virtually contiguous" memory (means contiguous virtual address region).