# ensure the DMA -capable memory

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, dma

I was reading section 'Part Id' of the following [document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt) I'm not sure how relevant this document to kernel 2.6.35 for instance; specifically it says:

```
..the DMA address of the memory must be within the dma_mask of the device..
```

and they recommend to pass certain flags, such as `GFP_DMA`, to `kmalloc`, so that it ensures the memory will fall within DMA mask provided.

However if the memory is allocated from cache pool created by `kmem_cache_create`, and with `kmem_cache_alloc(.. GFP_ATOMIC)`, this doesn't meet requirements outlined in DMA-API.txt ?

On the other hand, LDD talks about `__GFP_DMA` flag with regard to legacy ISA devices, therefore I'm not sure this is applicable to PCI/PCIe devices.

This is x86 64-bit platform if it matters:

```
pci_set_dma_mask(dev, 0xffffffffffffffffULL);
pci_set_consistent_dma_mask(dev, 0xffffffffffffffffULL);
```

I would appreciate to hear some explanations on it.

Answer (score 2):

1. For GFP_* for DMA

   On x86:

   - ISA - when using `kmalloc()` need to bitwise-or `GFP_DMA` with `GFP_KERNEL` (or `_ATOMIC`) because of the following:

     `GFP_DMA` guarantees:

     (1) physical addresses are consecutive when `get_free_page` returns more than one page and

     (2) only addresses lower than `MAX_DMA_ADDRESS` are returned. `MAX_DMA_ADDRESS` is 16MB on the PC because of ISA constraings
   - PCI -   don't need to use `GFP_DMA` because there is no `MAX_DMA_ADDRESS` limit
2. The `dma_mask` is checked by the device when calling `dma_map_*` or `dma_alloc_coherent`.

   `dma_alloc_coherent` ensures the memory allocated is able to be used by `dma_map_*` which gives other benifits too. (the implementation may choose to ignore flags that affect the location of the returned memory, like GFP_DMA)

You can refer to http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/sysHackfest/uploads/58/DMA_howto.1.txt

Comment: thanks. Another requirement I read in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt is that "it is recommended that driver writers map virtual regions that begin and end on page boundaries". What kernel API guarantee allocation in units of pages? It kmem_alloc_cache fine for this?

Comment: `__get_free_page()` and `__get_free_pages()` are what you want. `kmem_alloc_cache` won't guarantee to give you a full page.

Comment: You can refer to `/mm/page_alloc.c` for more kernel API for alloc pages.

Comment: You can pass `SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN` flag to `kmem_cache_create` to ensure all the memory you get from `kmem_cache_alloc` are cache line aligned. `kmalloc` does the similar thing, too. So `kmalloc` can also guarantee the memory is cache line aligned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949446/kmem-cache-creates-contiguous-memory/31958181#31958181 you mention that kmem_cache_alloc returns 1+ contiguous pages, so it does guarantee at least one full page?

Comment: It allocates 1+ contiguous **internally** which is called **slabs**. But you can't get a slab directly by calling `kmem_cache_*`. Instead the size of memory `kmem_cache_alloc` returns to you is the `size` you give `kmem_cache_create` before it.